# The letter x keeps appearing mysteriously even with my brand new keyboard

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

I have Windows 7 Home Edition. With me, I see x's appear when my hands are not even on the keyboard usually in a text box or window where the cursor is, but sometimes even in text boxes that are on the screen but where I don't have the cursor. I don't think it's the keyboard at all.  I'm on my second keyboard (brand new) and the x's are appearing just as frequently as they did with my old keyboard.  That's the whole reason why I bought the new keyboard.  The x key is definitely not stuck.  I think it's in the system software or is caused my a virus somewhere.

Comment: What exactly is your question? You defined a problem, but not the question.

Comment: It's a ghost. Have you upset any spirits recently?

Answer (score 0):

Try 
http://www.prevx.com/ - Some false positives with some benchmarking software I was using.
After checking for rootkits,
Disconnect all devices from the computer except mouse, keyboard, network and monitor.
Does problem still happen?
If yes, disconnect network.
Still happen?
Try a different keyboard. See if the problems still occur.

You might also try this

1. Disconnect USB keyboard
2. Uninstall keboard drivers from Device manager
3. Plug keyboard back in
4. Should autodetect and install or scan for new hardware.